# Error raised when trying to POST image to php using Requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to upload a .jpg file to a server using HTTP POST with the requests library in Python 3.7.

Target URL has some PHP code that handles the upload, taking 'fileToUpload' as the multipart variable.

I tried putting the request into a with-statement, changing the data=files to files=files (as recommended by some example code), or setting the headers to multipart/form-data (which should not be necessary for this library)

```py
import requests

url = 'http://someurl.com/upload/dir/post.php'
files = {'fileToUpload' : open('image.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, data=files)
```

If I run the script I raise every single error message in the post.php file, while if I take the thing to Insomnia or Postman the upload works just fine, so the server-side seems to be working.

Comment: It would be better if you can add the error with your question

Comment: Hi @RajanSharma thanks for your suggestion. I don't get an error in the script per se, but rather the response from the server consists of three error messages:
'File already exists' (it does not), 'Only jpg, jpeg, png files' (it is) and the general 'Your file was not uploaded'
The server-side php file matches the one from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

As I said, using different environment like postman works.